# Recursive function is only resolving if it runs once

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I have a recursive function that calls itself. Because it is in a promise, when I call it again, the promise chains and it seems like I cant get out even though im returning it. Here is my function...

```
let depth = 0;
const maxDepth = 1;

main();

function main()
{
    reccursive.then(
    function(response)
    {
        console.log('all finished!');
    });
}

function reccursive()
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>
  {
        console.log('in recursive function');

        if (depth === maxDepth)
        {
            console.log('hit max depth');
            return resolve();
        }

        console.log('not max depth, increasing');
        depth++;

        return reccursive();
  });
}
```

If the max depth is 0, it will run once and then resolve just fine.

Comment: You never resolve the Promise inside the recursive function. You need to just call `resolve()`, not `return resolve()`.

Comment: I am doing return resolve(); which would resolve the promise wouldnt it? And when I call it again, im returning whatever value it returns, in this case the resolve.

Comment: ok i will try that, one second

Comment: You only resolve the 'deepest' promise. For every time you call `new Promise` there should also be 1 call to `resolve()`. This is a _very bad_ way to implement this though. Don't use `new Promise()`.

Comment: i took away the return and that didnt work. How else would i do a promise if I dont do new promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing resolve for first call. instead of `return reslove()` use 
`reccursive().then(function(){ resolve();});`

```
let depth = 0;
const maxDepth = 1;

main();

function main()
{
reccursive.then(
  function(response)
 {
    console.log('all finished!');
 });
}

function reccursive()
{
 return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>
{
    console.log('in recursive function');

    if (depth === maxDepth)
    {
        console.log('hit max depth');
        return resolve();
    }

    console.log('not max depth, increasing');
    depth++;

    reccursive().then(function(){ resolve();});
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I changed it abit and did reccursive().then(resolve); instead. Thankyou, i can accept this in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

The question is, do you need to create multiple Promises ? If not, then create one promise and have an inner function that acts like the recursive function.

```js
function recursive(depth = 0, maxDepth = 5)
{

  console.log('in recursive function');
  function inner(resolve){
    if (depth === maxDepth){
        console.log('hit max depth');
        resolve(depth);
        return;
    }

    console.log('not max depth, increasing');
    depth++;
    inner(resolve);
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
       inner(resolve);    
  });
}

recursive().then(depth=>console.log(depth))
```